# Change boolean value with handleClick in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, boolean, components

I'm working on a small component which is essentially a button that allows a user to click to see a small shopping cart overlay.

If "showCart" is false (AKA the button is not clicked), the cart should be invisible. If the button is clicked, "showCart" should become true and thus render the  component.

I try clicking on the button and while I do get my console.log message "Button clicked", my Cart overlay doesn't appear. Can anyone give me some insight as to why this isn't working?

```
class ViewCart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { showCart: false }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState ={ showCart: true} 
    console.log("button clicked")

  }
  render() { 
    return (
      <div> 
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}> Show Cart 
        {this.state.showCart ? <Cart />: null }
        </button>

        </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not changing state in right manner, Code for change state will be like this  `this.setState({ showCart: true})`
Replace `handleClick` function from below code.

```
 handleClick() {
    this.setState({ showCart: true}) 
    console.log("button clicked")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You update your [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) the wrong way :)

```
handleClick() {
  this.setState({ showCart: true})
  console.log("button clicked")
}
```